# Synchronization of multiple Kafka consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

There are two Kafka topics. Each of them has only one partition. I have a Java application with two Kafka consumers:

- first consumer for the first Kafka topic
- second consumer for the second Kafka topic

These consumers perform some changes in the database and they are synchronized using in-memory locks.
Now I need to run additional instance of this application to provide high availability. But also I need to ensure that both consumers will run on the same instance of application . Otherwise I will not be able to syncronize them using in-memory locks. In general, if something bad happens with one consumer then all of them should stop on one instance and run on another.

[image]

I was trying to use `@KafkaListener(topics = {topic1", topic2"}, concurrency=2)` with `RoundRobinAssignor`. But in the end it also creates two consumers which behave independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end to solve this issue I've implemented custom assignor using this article https://medium.com/streamthoughts/understanding-kafka-partition-assignment-strategies-and-how-to-write-your-own-custom-assignor-ebeda1fc06f3

Answer (score 0):

Kafka consumer groups have their own form of locks... You can only have one consumer thread per partition. Consumers only parallelize over partitions of one topic, not multiple topics.

If you deploy two instances of your app, it'll be a warm standby, and will wait for the Kafka consumer group to rebalance after the first instance dies

Comment: True, consumer group helps to have only one active consumer per partition.  However, rebalancing can happen even when first instance is alive. For example, we might have situation when consumers 1 and 4 are active and 2 , 3 - passive.

Comment: Correct, but only if "1 and 4" or "2 and 3" are assigned the same singular partition topics... Note: You can create separate KafkaListener methods. You don't need to put concurrency=2 with two topics. But regarding stopping them, you can get access to the lifecycle hooks of the Kafka container to stop the consumer on an exception, or before the spring app ends